# Why is the height of my divs coming out greater than the body?

Tags: css, layout, html, css-float

Here is my `style.css` for a Wordpress theme based on Blankslate (I've changed none of the PHP. I just started the CSS).

I've highlighted the elements' borders to make them visible... and all of the content is overflowing out of the `body` border. This is the CSS in its entirety:

```css
/* = CSS Reset 
-------------------------------------------------- */

html,body,div,span,applet,object,iframe,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,p,blockquote,pre,a,abbr,acronym,address,big,cite,code,del,dfn,em,img,ins,kbd,q,s,samp,small,strike,strong,sub,sup,tt,var,b,u,i,center,dl,dt,dd,ol,ul,li,fieldset,form,label,legend,table,caption,tbody,tfoot,thead,tr,th,td,article,aside,canvas,details,embed,figure,figcaption,footer,header,hgroup,menu,nav,output,ruby,section,summary,time,mark,audio,video{font-size:100%;font:inherit;padding:0;border:0;margin:0;vertical-align:baseline}body{line-height:1}ol,ul{list-style:none}blockquote,q{quotes:none}blockquote:before,blockquote:after,q:before,q:after{content:'';content:none}table{border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0}article,aside,details,figcaption,figure,footer,header,hgroup,menu,nav,section{display:block}.sticky{}.bypostauthor{}.wp-caption{}.wp-caption-text{}.gallery-caption{}.alignright{}.alignleft{}.aligncenter{}


/* =Highlight
highlight the basic structural elements of the site
-------------------------------------------------- */

body {border: thin solid red;}

#sidebar {border: thin solid blue;}
#content {border: thin solid green;}

/* =Structure
-------------------------------------------------- */

body {
    width: 1000px;
    float: center;
    margin: auto;
}

#sidebar {
    width: 300px;
    float: right;
}
#content {
    width: 500px;
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a container with `overflow:hidden` around your floats (for some reason, this doesn't seem to work directly on `body` as I thought it should). See [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/PgLEa/).

And remove `float:center`, there's no such float value. To center the `body` horizontally (or any other block having a width), your `margin: auto` is enough.

Comment: More information on clearfix (which is what they are referencing): http://www.webtoolkit.info/css-clearfix.html

Comment: :( the elements are still coming out of the red outline... I don't get it, shouldn't it automatically adjust anyway? no CSS tutorial I've ever seen suggests one need do anything special for the divs not to come out of the body. I've also tried `clewar: both;`.

Comment: @fakaff See updated answer, I thought that would work on the `body` element, but it doesn't. And no, it should not automatically adjust as you're expecting. Floats are "out of the flow", meaning they don't take any space inside their parents unless they're cleared.

Comment: @AndrewKandels Not really, `clear:both` (and "clearfix") work by clearing the floats *after* the float container, while the `overflow` trick works on the container itself. See [here](http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css-clearing-floats-with-overflow).

Comment: @bfavaretto works! thank you it was driving me mad. the `id="wrapper"` container (introduced in `header.php`) seems to encapsulate all of the content. -- only question now is why this is not brought up in any tutorial I've searched for the last hour :/

Comment: @fakaff I'm glad it worked. Any decent tutorial on floats *should* mention they're out of the flow, how to clear them, and what happens if you don't. Maybe you're reading the wrong tutorials. Try this one: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/css-floats-101/.

Answer (score 0):

try with:

```
body {
  clear: both;
}
```

or append a div at the end of body with clear:both css

something like

```
<body>
  <div id='sidebar'></div>
  <div id='content'></div>
  <div class='clear'></div>
</body>
```

and the css

```
.clear {
  clear: both;
}
```

the problem is that you are floating all the content of the body tag

Answer (score 0):

I got my one working by setting both the body and the html to overflow hidden & adding some bottom padding to the body:

```
html {
overflow: hidden;
}

body {
overflow: hidden;
padding-bottom: 2%;
}
```